# Accessing JIRA from Jenkinsfile pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jira, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile, I want to query JIRA for some specific data, e.g. a list of released versions. Additionally, I want to create a ticket for a specific version.

The JIRA plugins I know, we can do several things like releasing a version or updating an issue, but not the things I mentioned. Is it possible to call the JIRA REST API from within the Groovy script and use the JIRA credentials provided in the Jenkins configuration somehow to do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

You can use withCredentials()

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
  set +x
  curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD https:jira**** > output.json
  }
```

Note: If your passowrd or username has special character, encode it before passing

```
String encoded_password = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(env.PASSWORD, "UTF-8")
```

Required Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin